# Parameterizing rendering of parent component from child

Tags: reactjs

I have a Parent component that contains a Child component. Suppose that the Parent wants to ask the Child its preferred background color and uses it to modify how the Parent renders itself:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
   favoriteColor = () => "red";
   render = () => (<span>Hello world</span>);
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  render = () => {
    const child = (<Child />);
    return (
      <div style={{backgroundColor: child.favoriteColor()}}>
        {child}
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

What is the idiomatic way to do this in React?

---

In my real project, I have a Parent component that has a dynamic set of children. The Parent wraps each child in a React Bootstrap `<Col>`. But sometimes a child does not want to be rendered, and the correct thing would be to omit the `<Col>`. So the Parent component needs to be able to ask each child "do you have anything to render?"

Comment: I don't think this is possible try creating function in Parent and letting child access that function through props and once function  is ran it will change value in Parent then pass it to the background color might work that way

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this *depending on the circumstances* is to declare `Child.favoriteColor` as `static`. As a static function it has no access to the instance's props or state.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
   static favoriteColor = () => "red";
   render = () => (<span>Hello world</span>);
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  render = () => {
    return (
      <div style={{backgroundColor: Child.favoriteColor()}}>
        <Child />
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```